# Getting the highest element from an array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, cart

I have a query which gives me a tuple of a discount added into database.

Here's the query

```
$discount_info = $this->autoload_model->get_data_from_table("td_discount,td_userdiscount","*",
                                               "td_discount.discount_id = td_userdiscount.discount_id
                                                AND td_discount.discount_code = '$coupon'")->result_array();
```

Now i have script which does the specific function.

There will be a condition, if the value of a index will be 1, then the code snippet is like this

```
if($discount_info[0]['discount_on']=="3")
    {
        $discount_product = $discount_info[0]['discount_product']; // its an id(autoincrement value)//
        if($discount_info[0]['applicable_type']==1)
        {
            $item_info = $this->autoload_model->get_data_From_table("td_product","*","product_id = '$discount_product'")->result_array();
            foreach($this->cart->contents() as $ci)
            {
                if($ci['name'] = $item_info[0]['product_name']
                {
                    // get the cart_item with the highest price if the product name matches//
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My cart structure is like this

```
$data = array(
                'id'      => $id,
                'qty'     => $qty,
                'price'   => $price,
                'name'    => $name,
                'options' => array(
                                    'picture'=>$img,
                                    'item_slug'=>$slug,
                                    'item_color'=>$color,
                                    'item_size'=>$size,
                                    'unit_price'=>$price,
                                    'order_type'=>$order_type,
                                    'product_type'=>$pro_type,
                                    'unit_discount' => 0.00,
                                    'item_discount' => 0.00,
                                    'discount_type' => '',
                                    )
                );
```

Now, its all set up, but I just can't get the login which I shall put over here

```
// get the cart_item with the highest price if the product name
```

Comment: What's the problem here? Find max value of array?

Comment: yes, the max value of the array, i mean the item with ci['price'] as the maximum

Comment: So use classic algorithm: start with `$max = 0; if ($max < $price) $max = $price;`

Comment: Pastebin sample http://pastebin.com/C7EDTbj1

Answer (score 2):

I imagine you could just define a

```
$highest = array('price' => 0);
```

before the loop and then inside the loop go:

```
// get the cart_item with the highest price if the product name matches//
if ($ci['price'] > $highest['price']) {
    $highest = $ci;
}
```

That way $highest would contain the best match at the end.